# No permission error in Firebase Cloud Function

Tags: firebase, express, google-cloud-functions

I want to implement a Slack authentication with Passport.js + Firebase Cloud Function. But when I redirected URL, the forbidden error occurs.

The error:

> Your client does not have permission to get URL /api/auth/slack?uid=XXXXXXXXXXX&redirectTo=http://localhost:3000 from this server.

The React code:

```
const slackAuthorizeURL = (uid) =>
  `https://us-central1-xxxxxxxxx.cloudfunctions.net/api/auth/slack?uid=${uid}&redirectTo=${window.location.href}`

<a href={slackAuthorizeURL}>Sign in with Slack</a>
```

The Server code:

```
const express = require('express')
const session = require('express-session')
const app = express()
const allowedOrigins = [
  'http://localhost:3000',
]
const allowCrossDomain = (req, res, next) => {
  const origin = req.headers.origin
  if (allowedOrigins.includes(origin)) {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', origin)
  }
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,POST')
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type')
  next()
}
app.use(allowCrossDomain)

app.use(session({ secret: config.session.secret }))

const passport = require('passport')

app.use(passport.initialize())
app.use(passport.session())
app.get('/auth/slack', (req, res, next) => {
  req.session.uid = req.query.uid
  req.session.redirectTo = req.query.redirectTo
  passport.authenticate('slack')(req, res, next)
})
```

I have already set up `allUsers` to `Cloud Functions Admin` on api in Google Cloud Platform.

Answer (score 1):

I missed to set up allUsers to Cloud Functions Admin on api in Google Cloud Platform correctly.

https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/managing-access#allowing_unauthenticated_function_invocation